# Simplicial homology of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Imagine the grid $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a simplicial complex such that each square is triangulated into two triangles, that is, the simplices are given by $\{(a, b),(a + 1, b),(a + 1, b + 1)\}$ and $\{(a, b),(a, b + 1),(a + 1, b + 1)\}$ for each $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Obviously the homology of this complex is trivial but in dimension zero where it is the integers.

However, I have no idea how to compute the first and second homology group. I really would like to go by definition and make formal that 'every cycle is bounded' and not to use things like homotopy invariance.

Comment: What didi you try ? Did you try to solve $d\omega = 0$ ?

Comment: Which ordering would I have to use?

Comment: Did you try to prove the same result for the real line equipped with the standard simplicial structure? Is there any example where you know how to compute simplicial homology using the definition?

Comment: Only in small finite examples where I can check by hand if a chain is a cycle. How would one proceed for the real line? Maybe this already shows me the way for the above example.

Comment: Then I suggest, you start with the real line. As a hint: a simplicial chain in ${\mathbb R}$ will be a formal finite sum $\sigma=\sum_i a_i [b_i,c_i]$. One of the numbers $c_i$, say, $c_n$,  will be the largest.Now, compute $\partial \sigma$ and watch for appearances of $c_n$ in that expression. Could it possibly cancel out (as it supposed to, if $\sigma$ is a cycle)?